# How can I add custom metadata to calender objects via MS Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm trying to write a calendar sync using the MS Graph API, i.e. I'm trying to sync events in a local DB to one or several newly created M365 calendars via Graph. In order to keep track of the created calendars, I need to store custom metadata with each calendar. It appears that [single-value extended property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty?view=graph-rest-1.0) is the way to add my local ID to the created calendar.

Unfortunately I fail to grasp how to do that: the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty-post-singlevalueextendedproperties?view=graph-rest-1.0#request-2) describes a simple enough request to write the data:

```json
{
  "singleValueExtendedProperties": [
      {
         "id":"String {66f5a359-4659-4830-9070-00047ec6ac6e} Name Color",
         "value":"Green"
      }
    ]
}
```

But the json references a GUID which, in its [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/extended-properties-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0#id-formats), references the [Exchange Server Protocols Master Property List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxprops/f6ab1613-aefe-447d-a49c-18217230b148) but I don't understand how they're all connected with each other: do I need to select an ID from the [Exchange Server Protocols Master Property List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxprops/37dd7329-97a4-42ff-974d-d805ac4d7211)? Is it possible to create a custom GUID? Do I need to create a [schema extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/schemaextension?view=graph-rest-1.0) (which doesn't seem to be possible for calendar resource types)?

So, how do I add custom metadata to my calendars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a custom named property, it must be identified by the extended property type, property set identifier, and a string name.

Extended property identifier (id):

`<property_type> <property_set_guid> Name <name_of_custom_property>`

Property type specifies the data type of a property value. Common values are `String`, `Integer`, `StringArray` and `IntegerArray`.

Property set is a set of attributes, identified by a GUID. Several of the more common property sets are described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxprops/cc9d955b-1492-47de-9dce-5bdea80a3323). You can use GUID for `PS_PUBLIC_STRINGS` (`{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}`) property set name.

String name is a name of your custom property.

Example to create an extended property for a calendar.

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{calendar-id}

Content-Type: application/json

{
    "singleValueExtendedProperties": [
        {
            "id": "String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name YourPropertyName",
            "value": "PropertyValue" // local ID you want to store
        }
    ]
}
```

Get property value by using `$expand` query with `$filter` inside the expand.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{calendar-id}?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name YourPropertyName')
```

Resources:

[Commonly Used Property Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxprops/cc9d955b-1492-47de-9dce-5bdea80a3323)

Comment: Wonderful, I've successfully written and read my property. But isn't it risky to just take `PS_PUBLIC_STRINGS`? Any other application with write access may over rite or just delete my data there. Is there a way to restrict access to the data, e.g. namespace it?

Comment: @Beat Not sure if you can restrict access to the data to avoid deletion. If other application wants to read/edit your custom extended property it needs to know the exact id "String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name YourPropertyName". I think that there is no way to list all extended properties.